PHP Laravel Vapor deploy staging not working
When I try to run php vendor/bin/vapor deploy staging I get this message in the console:
A valid subscription is required to perform this action.      - The subscription of your current team owner prevents you from carrying out this action.

This is the first time I'm seeing this. It has worked perfectly every time before. Does anyone know how I can fix this?
I have tried to search for a solution online but can't find the right help.

Can you share your configuration? Have you ensure the correct credentials are loaded?
